# How to build and create ./parking_lot file in java project

Tags: java, maven, compilation

Please have a look at this git repo :

https://github.com/rohitdang/ParkingLot

In the root folder, there is a named "parking_lot". To run this file, all I have to do is to type in the terminal:

```
./parking_lot <inputFile.path>
```

I want to create a similar file to execute a maven project so that in the root folder, I can run my project in similar fashion. I am using java-11 and IntelliJ IDEA.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`parking_lot` (https://github.com/rohitdang/ParkingLot/blob/master/parking_lot) is a file starting with:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSELF=`which "$0" 2>/dev/null`
[ $? -gt 0 -a -f "$0" ] && MYSELF="./$0"
java=java
if test -n "$JAVA_HOME"; then
    java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
java_args=-Xmx1g
exec "$java" $java_args -jar $MYSELF "$@"
exit 1 
PK^C^D
```

This is a valid shell script relaunching `java -jar` on itself.  This will work because `parking_lot` is *also* a valid jar file, as can be seen from

```
ravn@freewifi Downloads % jar tvf parking_lot
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:26 CEST 2017 META-INF/
   183 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/Exception/
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/inputargconfigfactory/
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/parkinglotfactory/
   720 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/Exception/InternalServerErrorException.class
   687 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/Exception/NotFoundException.class
  1680 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/inputargconfigfactory/FileParser.class
   988 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/inputargconfigfactory/InputArgumentConfigFactory.class
  1629 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/inputargconfigfactory/InputArgumentParser.class
   921 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/inputargconfigfactory/ParkingLotConfig.class
   809 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/ParkingLot.class
   898 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/parkinglotfactory/Car.class
  1877 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/parkinglotfactory/CreateParkingLot.class
  1942 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/parkinglotfactory/Leave.class
  2303 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/parkinglotfactory/Park.class
  1774 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/parkinglotfactory/ParkingLotConfigFactory.class
  2519 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/parkinglotfactory/RegistrationNumberForCarWithColours.class
  2986 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/parkinglotfactory/SlotNumberForCarWithColours.class
  3043 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/parkinglotfactory/SlotNumberForCarWithRegistrationNumber.class
  1998 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 com/gojek/parkinglot/ParkingLot/parkinglotfactory/Status.class
    60 Wed Oct 18 01:29:22 CEST 2017 file_input_invalid.txt
   418 Wed Oct 18 01:29:22 CEST 2017 file_inputs_valid.txt
   397 Wed Oct 18 01:29:22 CEST 2017 file_inputs_without_creating_parking_lot.txt
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:26 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:26 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/com.gojek.parkinglot/
     0 Wed Oct 18 01:29:26 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/com.gojek.parkinglot/ParkingLot/
  1666 Wed Oct 18 01:24:22 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/com.gojek.parkinglot/ParkingLot/pom.xml
   124 Wed Oct 18 01:29:24 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/com.gojek.parkinglot/ParkingLot/pom.properties
```

(This is possible because jar files are zip files and they are read from the *end* of the file.  The `PK` right after `exit 1` is the first bit of the zip header)

I would guess that the file was created simply by concatenating the shell script with the jar file generated by Maven. Use the `cat` command for this.